# Cannot watch a variable's unicode value in VSCode (C++ MinGW)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I came up with this problem when I tried to set the unicode value for a variable: `u16string uni = u"\u4F60\u597D";`. When I run this program and watch this variable, it just appeared inproperly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    u16string uni = u"\u4F60\u597D";         // unicode "你好"
    string mtb = "\344\275\240\345\245\275"; // utf-8 "你好" e4 bd a0 e5 a5 bd
    string mtb2 = "你好";                    // gbk "你好" c4 e3 ba c3

    // gbk: "浣犲ソ" e4 bd a0 e5 a5 bd

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> conversion;
    std::string mbs = conversion.to_bytes(uni.c_str()); // ni hao (你好)

    cout << mtb << endl;
    cout << mbs << endl;
    cout << mtb2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: here is the watch window]

However, if I use the multibyte form to value a variable: `string mtb = "\344\275\240\345\245\275";` It appears as normal.

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: out of curiosity, what if your prefix the `mtb2` utf8 string literal with `u8`? Like `u8"<ni hao>"` ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)) And how do `mtb` and `uni` appear in the "watch" panel?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem by Enabling UTF-8 on GDB: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6790

Comment: see [answer] (and [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)) :)

Comment: I try your solution by adding the prefix `u8`, and it works. It appears in the watch window as `mtb2: "你好"`. And if I change the `uni` into `string uni = u8"\u4F60\u597D"; `, it also works.@user

Comment: It seems that this problem is related to my locale setting. The default `chcp` in CMD is 936(GBK) on my PC, while the program is written and compiled in UTF-8. I found a strange phenomenon. As for the original code `string mtb2 = "你好";`, it shows properly in CMD as `"你好"` but `"��"` in the watch window. However,  for the new code `string mtb2 = u"你好"`, it shows properly as `"你好"` in the watch window, but shows as `"浣犲ソ"` in CMD.  Interestingly, `"浣犲ソ"`'s GBK code is `e4 bd a0 e5 a5 bd`, similar to `"你好"`'s UTF-8 code. I'm confused about the reason why these two codes behave differently. @user

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be caused by multiple reasons. A straight way to solve this issue is to **Enable UTF-8 on GDB**.

Adding `set charset UTF-8` to the `setupCommands` in the `Launch.json` file fixs it.

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
        "text": "set charset UTF-8"
    }
]
```

[image: modify the result]